# Getting S3 static site to resolve on .com/my_url.html instead of .com/index.html

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a static site in an S3 bucket. I've pointed my custom domain to my s3 bucket, and navigating to the domain name loads the html page from my s3 bucket as I set it up in the bucket properties. I picked a different HTML file from index.html because my client would like for users to end up on "mycompany.com/my-page-name-with-keywords.html" for SEO purposes. (The bucket has an index.html file, it's a copy of the "my-page-name-with-keywords.html" page, but I think it is not being used since I set the index to be my-page-name-with-keywords.html).

Right now the address bar shows the URL "mycompany.com" but I would like to load the html page and show the HTML name in the address bar e.g., "mycompany.com/my-page-name-with-keywords."

How can I achieve this with S3? Maybe set the A record to include /my-page-name-with-keywords.html in Route 53?

Also does having keywords in the home page URL have real SEO benefits?

Comment: You could use route 53 or any domain resolver to alias the url to your domain provided you purchase the domain. Also, Stack Overflow is for questions concerning software development. You may have better luck with https://serverfault.com/ for this sort of question.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I will research at serverfault.com